# Move desktop wallpaper to the side

Tags: macos, desktop

iMac desktop photo is in the middle of the screen. I want to move the photo to one side so my desktop folders are on the other side.

Answer (score 2):

The Mac does not have a way (built-in) to show the desktop picture on just half of the screen.

What you *could* do, however is to open that picture in your picture editing program of choice, make a new picture with just a single color you like and then shrink the photo you want down a bit so it is only on the left or right side of the screen. Once it is positioned correctly save it as a JPG in your pictures folder and select that as your new desktop picture.

Comment: I’ve seen people that do this and overlay text with calendar information, to-do and tickler reminders and more.

Comment: That would be a third-party app. A search of the app store and other places might yield something that does what you want.

Comment: Preview, screen markup all work in a pinch.